# Was Jesus as the Lamb of God, offered without spot or blemish?

Tags: resurrection

The greater proof to me, if I were one of the disciples, after witnessing a bloody and beaten Christ on the cross, if He had appeared without any wounds. Otherwise, He could have appeared to have been resuscitated.

> John 1:29 - The next day John saw Jesus coming toward him and said,
> “Look, the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!

> Heb 9:14 - how much more will the blood of Christ, who through the
> eternal Spirit offered Himself unblemished to God, purify our
> consciences from works of death, so that we may serve the living God!
>
> 1 Peter 1:18, 19 - For you know that it was not with perishable things
> such as silver or gold that you were redeemed from the empty way of
> life you inherited from your forefathers, but with the precious blood
> of Christ, a lamb without blemish or spot.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Valid question here need a specific Bible verse to examine.  I will add this for you.

Answer (score 5):

There is an interesting pattern in the NT concerning the Messiah, typified by the sacrificial lamb "without spot and without blemish."  However, I would add another to the OP list:

> Heb 7:26, 27 - Such a high priest truly befits us—One who is **holy,
> innocent, undefiled, set apart from sinners**, and exalted above the
> heavens. Unlike the other high priests, He does not need to offer
> daily sacrifices, first for His own sins and then for the sins of the
> people; He sacrificed for sin once for all when He offered up Himself.

The OP has quoted the key NT texts that use the metaphor/symbol of the sacrificial lamb of God for Jesus Christ.  However, the same is also recorded of the saved saints:

- Eph 1:4 - For He chose us in Him before the foundation of the world to be **holy and blameless** in His presence. In love ...
- Eph 5:27 - and to present her to Himself as a glorious church, **without stain or wrinkle or any such blemish, but holy and blameless**.
- 1 Tim 6:14 - Keep this commandment **without stain or reproach** until the appearance of our Lord Jesus Christ,
- 2 Peter 3:14 - Therefore, beloved, as you anticipate these things, make every effort to be found at peace—**spotless and blameless** in His sight.
- Rev 14:5 - And in their mouth **no lie** was found; they are **blameless**.

**CONCLUSION**

The description of the ancient sacrificial lamb as "without spot and blemish" referred to the lamb's physical appearance and qualities.  This physical sacrificial lamb was used as a symbol of the sacrificial Messiah whose sinless **character** was without spot and blemish.  The Messiah's people, forgiven and saved saints, are similarly described.

Comment: Very good answer. You used character. I would have used spirit. Nonetheless same conclusion. The old Testament was about works of the flesh. The New Testament about the heart and soul. Ye must be born again. ( from above ; born of the Spirit as Billy Graham said.

Comment: Really says something about the efficacy of Jesus' blood with respect to your later verses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Jesus Christ was without 'spot or blemish'.  He would otherwise not have been the propitiation for the world's sin payment.

1 Peter 1:19

> But with the precious blood of Christ, as of a lamb without blemish and without spot:

Ephesians 5:27

> That he might present it to himself a glorious church, not having spot, or wrinkle, or any such thing; but that it should be holy and without blemish.

Romans 3:25

> Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;

Also, His disciples did not recognize Him post-resurrection. Christ was marred more than any man (Isaiah 52:14), but when He appeared again unto them He would have certainly not been in this transfigured state... or they might have recognized Him. Notice below that "He appeared in another form", and had to "open their eyes" to who He was.

Mark 16:9-14

> <sup>**9**</sup> Now when Jesus was risen early the first day of the week, he appeared first to Mary Magdalene, out of whom he had cast seven devils.
> <sup>**10**</sup> And she went and told them that had been with him, as they mourned and wept.
> <sup>**11**</sup> And they, when they had heard that he was alive, and had been seen of her, believed not.
> <sup>**12**</sup> After that he appeared in another form unto two of them, as they walked, and went into the country.
> <sup>**13**</sup> And they went and told it unto the residue: neither believed they them.
> <sup>**14**</sup> Afterward he appeared unto the eleven as they sat at meat, and upbraided them with their unbelief and hardness of heart, because they believed not them which had seen him after he was risen.

Luke 24:15-16

> <sup>**15**</sup> And it came to pass, that, while they communed together and reasoned, Jesus himself drew near, and went with them.
> <sup>**16**</sup> But their eyes were holden that they should not know him.

Luke 24:25-31

> <sup>**25**</sup> Then he said unto them, O fools, and slow of heart to believe all that the prophets have spoken:
> <sup>**26**</sup> Ought not Christ to have suffered these things, and to enter into his glory?
> <sup>**27**</sup> And beginning at Moses and all the prophets, he expounded unto them in all the scriptures the things concerning himself.
> <sup>**28**</sup> And they drew nigh unto the village, whither they went: and he made as though he would have gone further.
> <sup>**29**</sup> But they constrained him, saying, Abide with us: for it is toward evening, and the day is far spent. And he went in to tarry with them.
> <sup>**30**</sup> And it came to pass, as he sat at meat with them, he took bread, and blessed it, and brake, and gave to them.
> <sup>**31**</sup> And their eyes were opened, and they knew him; and he vanished out of their sight.

Christ risen kept their eyes blinded until they understood that OT prophecy had been fulfilled through His death, burial, and resurrection, then proving that He was indeed the Christ.

Comment: Where do you get the wording 'beyond recognition' ? Can you reference the Greek text, please ?

Comment: Thank you @NigelJ.  I corrected the statement to better line up with His description of "marred visage" in the verse from Isaiah 52:14.  (Greek OT)  ὃν τρόπον ἐκστήσονται ἐπὶ σὲ πολλοί--οὕτως ἀδοξήσει ἀπὸ ἀνθρώπων τὸ εἶδός σου καὶ ἡ δόξα σου ἀπὸ τῶν ἀνθρώπων--,
(KJV)  As many were astonied at thee; his visage was so marred more than any man, and his form more than the sons of men:

Comment: @NigelJ I also want to thank you regarding the correction of me transposing 2 Cor 5:19.  Our Q&A was deleted, so I was unable to admit to the error you noticed.  You were absolutely correct!  It was a careless/honest mistake on my part.  Peace and grace!

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated.